# ImportError: cannot import name 'ops' from 'object_detection.utils' (unknown location)

Tags: python, tensorflow, compiler-errors, real-time

I have error when running script for `import object_detection.utils`:

```
from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
```

and get this error:

[image]

I have succeeded in running `python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py` but still have the error.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.